# Android Menu Inflater conflict?

Tags: java, android, menu, r.java-file

So while doing this old tutorial, I'm having issues with import android.R (which I need for simple_list_item_1) but breaks my R.menu.cmenu (cmenu.xml), what am I missing here? ...and yes I have the xml setup.

```
import android.R;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity {

    String classes[] = {"MainActivity", "TextPlay", "Email", "Camera", "Data", "OpenedClass"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String cheese = classes[position];
        try{
        Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.test1." + cheese);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater blowUp;
        blowUp = getMenuInflater();
        blowUp.inflate(R.menu.cmenu, menu); //cmenu has the error: rename
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't import `android.R`. Use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` in place of `R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not import Android.R.

> Note: Eclipse sometimes likes to add an import android.R statement at the top of your files that use resources, especially when you ask eclipse to sort or otherwise manage imports. This will cause your make to break. Look out for these erroneous import statements and delete them.

http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html

Try to use

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

instead.